# Oracle 11g and SQL Server EPOCH-3600 and EPOCH (Unix_timestamp)

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need to write a select query that gets data in between `EPOCH(datetime)-3600` AND `EPOCH(datetime)`.

> select all incidents modified in specific date range between `EPOCH(datetime)-3600` AND `EPOCH(datetime)`

So my query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE COLUMN_NAME BETWEEN COLUMNNAME-3600 AND COLUMNNAME
```

Will this query get the data from 1 hour ago to the current time, in Unix TimeStamp format?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that works on Oracle **and** SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Given a column (`COLUMN_NAME`) where data is stored as a unix timestamp (eg number of seconds elapsed since January 1st, 1970), you are looking to filter records based on a `DATE` passed as parameter.

My understanding is that you need a way to convert a unix timestamp to a date. There is no such built-in function in Oracle, however you are allowed to add a number to a date, where the number represents the number of days to add.

Try :

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE 
    TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + COLUMN_NAME/60/60/24 -- convert unix timestamp to date
    BETWEEN :mydate - 3600 AND :mydate
;
```

Replace both `:mydate` with the actual `DATE` for which you want the search to be performed.

Comment: I'm not sure with this query but it is not included convert unix timestamp to date : select * from table_name where unix_col_Name between (select MAX(Unix_Col_name-3600) from table_name) and (select MAX(Unix_Col_name) from table_name)

Comment: @Sundeep, the part of the statement that converts a unix timestamp to date is :  `TO_DATE('01/01/1970', 'dd/mm/yyyy') + COLUMN_NAME/60/60/24`, where `COLUMN_NAME` contains the Unix timestamp. You can use it anywhere you need to convert a unix timestamp to a date